# Azure Get All Organzations in multi tenants

Tags: azure, api, azure-devops, azure-active-directory, postman

In this article https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resources/tenants/list I can get all the Tenants in my account. Now I want to get all the Organization in devops/vsts in each tenant or directory. Currently Im using this article https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/account/accounts/list?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0 and the token I get in the tenants is not working in getting all the organizations. Is theres a way to list all the organization in each tenant in my account? Thanks!

Comment: You can get this via azure API like shown here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resources/tenants/list

Comment: yeah i know, but i need to do this in Postman or C#

Comment: So what is the problem of doing it using postman you can get the appropriate token then make this Get call so easily via postman or via httpClient in c#?

Comment: I wrote an answer on how to gain access_token so you can use this call easily

Answer (score 0):

You can get the list via the below azure API call:

```
GET https://management.azure.com/tenants?api-version=2016-06-01
```

And for this API call to returns results correctly you need to gain access token and put it in the request header like that:

```
Authorization: Bearer access_token
```

And as shown in the documentation, you can gain the access_token from the below Identity end point as it's Implicit flow token:

```
Authorization URL: https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize
```

So the steps will be:

1- First make a call to:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize
```

With the appropriate parameters like the client_id and etc.

2- Gain access_token from the first step response.

3- Use this access_token to retrieve your talents list:

```
GET https://management.azure.com/tenants?api-version=2016-06-01
Authorization: Bearer access_token
```

And you can test this via postman or any curl based tool for verifying.

Comment: I'm ok with this API https://management.azure.com/tenants?api-version=2016-06-01. I can get all the list of tenants. Now my problem is that the user will select a tenant and then using this API https://app.vssps.visualstudio.com/_apis/accounts it will list all the Organization base on the tenantId that the user selected.